# Calculate difference in SQL Rows based on column value change

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a table which has below data

```
1   4619.71
1   4619.84
1   4619.97
1   4620.11
1   4620.11
1   4620.11
0   4620.11
0   4620.24
0   4620.24
0   4620.24
1   4620.24
1   4620.24
1   4620.24
1   4620.37
0   4620.37
```

I want to calculate the how much was the time used during value was 1. the best way i thought is check first when the value became 1 and then when it changed to 0. find the difference between that 0 and 1 and then find next 1 and then when it changed to 0. keep finding the difference from 0 and 1 and then in the end, Sum all the difference found those sets between 1 and 0.

Please help writing a query based on this logic.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: these are against userid, there is another column my usedid there in the table. i am expected just one row like below
rds  1   5.78

Comment: for all the different users, each user will have a one data row

Answer (score 0):

You could use a difference in row_numbers() to partition the data, then use that to calculate the values you need.

For example, using the sample data...

```
DECLARE @tblName TABLE (i INT, j DECIMAL(6,2));
INSERT @tblName VALUES (1, 4619.71),(1, 4619.84),(1, 4619.97),(1, 4620.11),(1, 4620.11),(1, 4620.11),(0, 4620.11)
,(0, 4620.24),(0, 4620.24),(0, 4620.24),(1, 4620.24),(1, 4620.24),(1, 4620.24),(1, 4620.37),(0, 4620.37), (1, 4620.88);


WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT i, j, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RN1 - RN2 ORDER BY j) RN3, RN1
    FROM (
        SELECT i, j
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j) RN1
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i ORDER BY j) RN2
        FROM @tblName) T)
SELECT C1.i, C1.j
     , C1.j - X.j [IndividualDifference]
     , SUM(ISNULL(C1.j - X.j, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY i) [SumDifference]
FROM CTE C1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(j)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN3 = 1
    AND RN1 < C1.RN1) X(j)
WHERE C1.RN3 = 1  
ORDER BY C1.j;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. i will take this approach and will let you know how it turns out with final implementation

Comment: I used the partition and it gave me the output i wanted. Thank you so much. Appreciate it